# how does cpu read 32 bit word from memory

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-hardware, cpu

I'm interested in how  does cpu read 32 bit word from memory .If the processor has 32 bits of address space then it can  address 4,294,967,295 locations  (or 4 gb) Does this mean that each location has 32 bits.?

Comment: What do you mean by "how"?

Comment: Modern computers are [byte addressable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing).  Each address refers to one 8-bit byte.  When the processor wants to load/store a larger size, consecutive addresses are accessed.   The memory understands these larger requests: several different transfer sizes can be requested as part of the cpu-memory bus protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Address Space and Word Size are indeed two different things. If my processor has an $n$ bit address space, then it can address $2^n$ addresses. Note that this is merely the number of addresses and is **not $2^n$ GB**.

The word size of a memory refers to the size of the smallest addressable unit of the memory. In other words if my processor has an $n$ bit address space and a word-size of $b$ bytes, then my processor can address $2^n$ locations each of which are $b$ bytes long.

Comment: Addresses are often byte-based even if the machine word is larger.

Comment: That cleared up a preconceived notion. Thanks.